# Transform array read by sys.stdin to "normal" format

Tags: python, numpy, format

I have one program that creates a magic square and an other one that should read the this output and verifys that it is a magic square.

With the secound program I read in the output from the first one with

```
array = []


for zeile in sys.stdin:
    zeile = str.strip(zeile)
    array.append(zeile)
```

This results in #(1)

```
['[17 24  1  8 15]', '[23  5  7 14 16]', '[ 4  6 13 20 22]', '[10 12 19 21  3]', '[11 18 25  2  9]']
```

What I need is #(2)

```
[17 24  1  8 15]
[23  5  7 14 16]
[ 4  6 13 20 22]
[10 12 19 21  3]
[11 18 25  2  9]
```

Which is made by the first program.

So my question is how I can format the result I get in #(1) so that i get the array which i need? (#(2))?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

I print the standard input which I'am getting form my first program to an external file and the i read it in and manipulate it so that it satisfys my needs

Here is some code:

```
data = open('magischesDreieckErzeugt.txt', 'w')
for zeile in sys.stdin:
    zeile = str.strip(zeile)
    print(zeile, file=data)
    if zeile == 'Bitte korrigieren Sie Ihre Eingabe!':
        print('Korrigieren Sie Ihre Eingabe im 1. Teil des Programms!')
        quit()
    else:
        print(zeile)
data.close()
```

And read it in with:

```
with open('magischesDreieckErzeugt.txt') as infile:
    quadrat = np.fromstring( infile.read().replace('[','').replace(']', ''), sep=' ')

# bestimme da maximum des arrays und ziehe die wurzel um die länge (= höhe) des arrays zu ermitteln
x = int(np.sqrt(np.max(quadrat)))

# formatiere das array in ein x mal x array im
quadrat = np.reshape(quadrat, (-1,x))
```